# Report file changes including removing lines

Tags: linux

I created a node.js app that passes the output of any command to a webhook. Now I need a command that outputs all file changes... I tried to use `tail -f ~/testfile.txt` but that only outputs additions made to the file... Not if I remove something. Is there a good way of doing something like this with pre-existing programs?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, that tells me when it was modified, but not what I changed... tail -f shows tells me that I added "Cookie" at the end of the file, but inotify only shows "modify" and not the content that was added/removed. Can git do something like that?

Comment: You have to narrow down your problem.  What do you mean by *any change*?  The most granular would be `write()` calls to the file.  There could be one for every character added, making this rather pointless.  Or you could make a copy of the file every *x* seconds and run `diff` if you mean "any change within *x* seconds". etc.